# Custom Format not showing on visualiser?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

When I apply a custom format to a field in my power bi model it does not apply same format to my visualisers. What additional settings must I apply?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a workaround.

I had to simply wrap all my DAX measures with:
FORMAT([Name of Measure], "#,##0.00")

However, when I deploy my Power BI model to the online service, then the customer format takes effect. Whether I explicity wrap my measures with FORMAT([],"#,##0.00") or not. I have to wrap my measures with the formatting I want to make it display formatting on my visuals, when I work with a local .pbix file.

**** Disclaimer, perhaps forcing a FORMAT([MEASURE], "#,##0.00") is not the best solution, because you will further have to wrap this to ensure that BLANKs remain BLANK ...

VAR result = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[SaleAmount]))

RETURN IF(ISBLANK(result), BLANK(), FORMAT(result, "#,##0.00"))